# Kotlin have two simultaneous activities

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity

I am developing an Android Kotlin application which uses two different activities. In each one I have a button that allow me to move to the other one, to say, in Activity 1 I have a button that calls the follwing:

```
val intentActivity2 = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
startActivity(intentActivity2)
```

This launches correctly Activity2, which similarly inside it I have another button that calls the first activity to return to it:

```
val intentActivity1 = Intent(this, Activity1::class.java)
startActivity(intentActivity1)
```

The problem I have is that I want to have both activities running simultaneously (not needed to be shown at screen at the same time), and the issue right now is that every time I call the "startActivity(intent)" a new activity is created, loosing what I had in the previous one, so when I return to Activity1 everything is reset and the same when I go once again to Activity2. Both activities work fine and do their work, the problem is that I can't freely conmute between them.

Is there a way to have both activities at the same time or to not start a new activity everytime I want to change to the other one?

Thank you,

Comment: You need [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: Yes, use viewModel and LiveData. Basically MVVM architecture might be solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As someone just said you need ViewModel to retrieve your data after deleting/creating new activities. Maybe you can use fragments to do your things. Fragments are attached to activities and it is easier to use them instead of ViewModel.